# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll

Tags: c#, nuget-package, discord.net

When I try to run my Discord.NET C# bot, a FileNotFoundException is thrown.
It also says:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My code is built on the sample in the documentation:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    DiscordSocketClient discordSocketClient = new DiscordSocketClient();

    discordSocketClient.Log += Log;
    discordSocketClient.MessageReceived += DiscordSocketClient_MessageReceived;

    await discordSocketClient.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "xxxx");
    await discordSocketClient.StartAsync();

    await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task DiscordSocketClient_MessageReceived(SocketMessage arg)
{
    // Do stuff...
}

private Task Log(LogMessage logMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(logMessage.ToString());
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It seems Visual Studio 15.8.0 Preview 5 has some bugs. So I've learnt my lesson about using pre-release software for production software.

I installed the stable release and recreated the project, and it's fixed :)